# Iteration over relations using a database

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog.

Consider the following format:

```
 carsCompany(Tel_Number,
   Manager,
   Company_Name,
   [new_cars(Car_Name,info(Color,Creator),Date_Creation)],
   [old_cars(Car_Name,info(Color,Creator),Date_Creation)]
   ]).
```

I would like to create a two argument relation which gets a list of car names and a company and adds them to the company.

```
update_company([Mazda],Company).
```

I have the following db example:

```
 carsCompany(1234,
   Jujiro Matsuda,
   Mazda,
   [new_cars(mazda_3,info(Grey,Person1),26082016)],
   [old_cars(Cosmo,info(Black,Person2),26081927),
   [old_cars(RX-7,info(Black,Person2),26081979),]
   ]).
```

What I tried to do is to get all the the possible cars using `member` so I could iterate over the information.

```
 member(X, [X|Xs]).
 member(X, [Y|Ys]) :- member(X, Ys).

 get_all(New,Old,carsCompany(_,_,_,New_Cars,Old_Cars)) :- member(New,New_Cars), member(Old, Old_Cars).
```

Although It doesn't really work:

```
New = [Lecture|_G750],
Old = [Tutorial|_G753] ;
New = [Lecture|_G750],
Old = [_G752, Tutorial|_G756] ;
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: *I'm new to Prolog*.... I wish I had a nickel for every Prolog question that started with this phrase. Anyway, why are you writing your own `member/2` predicate? Every Prolog implementation I know of has one already. And.... you need to show what query you entered to get the results you are showing. it's unclear how you want your query to work.

Comment: This is a syntax error: `carsCompany(1234,
   Jujiro Matsuda,
   Mazda, ...`

Comment: @lurker: Certainly you do not know YAP. Also SICStus 3 did not have `member/2`.

Comment: @false I know of YAP and SICStus but have not used them. Thanks for that bit of information! I just figured `member/2` was fundamental. I guess I was wrong in that assumption...

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
car_company( 1, 1234, person('Jujiro', 'Matsuda'), 'Mazda' ).

production( 1, cars, new, 'Mazda-3', info( gray,  person1 ), 26/08/2016 ).
production( 1, cars, old, 'Cosmo',   info( black, person2 ), 26/08/1927 ).
production( 1, cars, old, 'RX-7',    info( black, person2 ), 26/08/1979 ).

% query:
q :- 
    findall(
        new_car( ID, Model, Color ),
       (  
           car_company( ID, _ , person('Jujiro', 'Matsuda'), 'Mazda' ),
           production( ID, cars, new, Model, info( Color, _ ), _ )
       ),
       Result1
    ),
    writeq( Result1 ),
    findall(
        old_car( ID, Model, Color ),
        (   
            car_company( ID, Phone, person('Jujiro', 'Matsuda'), 'Mazda' ),
            production( ID, cars, old, Model, info( Color, _ ), _ )
        ),
        Result2
    ),                   
    writeq( Result2 ).
```