# Getting all facts that are known to prolog (with special format)

Tags: prolog

Prolog question:

Consider the following format:

```
 carsCompany(Tel_Number,
   Manager,
   Company_Name,
   [new_cars(Car_Name,info(Color,Creator),Date_Creation)],
   [old_cars(Car_Name,info(Color,Creator),Date_Creation)]
   ]).
```

I would like to get all information of the data that is known for this realtion.

Example:

```
 carsCompany(1234,
   Jujiro Matsuda,
   Mazda,
   [new_cars(mazda_3,info(Grey,Person1),26082016)],
   [old_cars(Cosmo,info(Black,Person2),26081927),
   [old_cars(RX-7,info(Black,Person2),26081979),]
   ]).
```

Will give me:

```
 New = new_cars(mazda_3,info(Grey,Person1),26082016)
 Old = old_cars(Cosmo,info(Black,Person2),26081927)
 New = new_cars(mazda_3,info(Grey,Person1),26082016)
 Old = old_cars(RX-7,info(Black,Person2),26081979)
```

I would like to get all possible members into `New` and `Old` so I could iterate over them. I know I need to use the `member` prediec. 
How can I do it?

Comment: What exactly does the query look like? Why would you want `New = new_cars(mazda_3,info(Grey,Person1),26082016)` twice? Also, `Cosmo` and `RX-7` are not valid Prolog atoms. `Cosmo` is a variable, and `RX-7` represents the term `'-'(RX, 7)` where `RX` is a variable. This is a syntax error: `carsCompany(1234,
   Jujiro Matsuda,
   Mazda,
   [new_cars(mazda_3,info(Grey,Person1),26082016)],
   [old_cars(Cosmo,info(Black,Person2),26081927),
   [old_cars(RX-7,info(Black,Person2),26081979),]
   ]).`

Comment: This is a repeat of this question,  with the same issues copied over: [Iteration over relations using a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047005/iteration-over-relations-using-a-database).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
car_company( 1, phone, person('Jujiro', 'Matsuda'), 'Mazda' ).

production( 1, cars, new, 'Mazda-3', info( gray,  person1 ), 26/08/2016 ).
production( 1, cars, old, 'Cosmo',   info( black, person2 ), 26/08/1927 ).
production( 1, cars, old, 'RX-7',    info( black, person2 ), 26/08/1979 ).

% query:
q :- 
findall(
   new_car( ID, Model ),
   (  
     car_company( ID, Phone, person('Jujiro', 'Matsuda'), 'Mazda' ),
     production( ID, cars, new, Model, info( Color, _ ), _ )
   ),
   Result1
   ),
   writeq( Result1 )
),
findall(
   old_car( ID, Model ),
   (   
   car_company( ID, Phone, person('Jujiro', 'Matsuda'), 'Mazda' ),
   production( ID, cars, old, Model, info( Color, _ ), _ )
   ),
   Result2
   ),                   
   writeq( Result2 ).
```